# Which power automate flow to use to copy sharepoint list elements with attachments into folders in a way that they keep all their metadata?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a sharepoint list which is receiving new items with attachments every day. I would like to sort these items by category and copy them into individual document folders. I tried a few power automate solutions but I can only copy the attachments of the items, no metadata is coming with them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "Get file metadata?"

[image]